# "Incorrect file parameter" when importing a .gz file in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I am having a problem in importing a .gz file in phpmyadmin. I would like to use it for a laravel project. The file that may be compressed in phpmyadmin are gzip, bzip2 or zip files only. I tried to convert it but it doesn't seem to work. I need suggestions

Comment: Is there an error message? Please share it here

Comment: @Derek yes. It says "Incorrect file parameter" in phpmyadmin.